# Downloading an (apache) online directory locally using cli (wget ...)

Tags: command-line, wget

Not really a question this one - but alternative answers are certainly welcome! :)

Sometimes I need to download files listed in an Apache directory listing, say as in:

- http://www.gnu-darwin.org/www001/src/ports/net/samba-libsmbclient/work/samba-3.0.28/source/libsmb/

... in a given directory on my computer, and I'd like to use command-line tools for that.

As far as `wget` is concerned, actually there are some switches that should be in place - noting that `wget` tends to either download single items - or to *reconstruct* the server folders locally!

As I just spent some half an hour figuring out what those proper switches are (to copy the remote files locally as through, say, FTP), I'd like to document them here; so the above link would be downloaded with:

```
wget -nd -r -l 1 http://www.gnu-darwin.org/www001/src/ports/net/samba-libsmbclient/work/samba-3.0.28/source/libsmb/
```

... where:

```
   -nd
   --no-directories
       Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving
       recursively.  With this option turned on, all files will get saved
       to the current directory, without clobbering [...]

   -r
   --recursive
       Turn on recursive retrieving.

   -l depth
   --level=depth
       Specify recursion maximum depth level depth.  The default maximum
       depth is 5.
```

It would be nice to hear alternatives to the above command - maybe using different set of switches for `wget` - or maybe using `curl` or other packages...

Comment: Also related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36798/sync-with-a-directory-listing-of-an-apache-server

Answer (score 6):

After some time, thanks to the pointers by @jw013 and in [Sync with a Directory Listing of An Apache Server - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36798/sync-with-a-directory-listing-of-an-apache-server), I finally found my "ultimate" `wget` command.

Assume you have a tree of files and directories in a directory called `myfiles_dir`, and let that directory be accessible through an Apache directory listing on `http://localhost/shared/myfiles_dir`. Then, you can sync directory locally with:

```
wget -r -N --no-parent --reject '*index.html*' -nH --cut-dirs=1 http://localhost/shared/myfiles_dir/
```

... where:

```
-r,  --recursive              specify recursive download.
-N,  --timestamping           don't re-retrieve files unless newer than
                              local.
-np, --no-parent              don't ascend to the parent directory.
-R,  --reject=LIST            comma-separated list of rejected extensions.
-nH, --no-host-directories    don't create host directories.
     --cut-dirs=NUMBER        ignore NUMBER remote directory components.
```

This will download the contents into a subdirectory `myfiles_dir` created in the directory `wget` was called from (the working directory), without any residual `index.html` files.

Note that the trailing slash `/` after the http link/address is extremely important: if it is not there - as in `http://localhost/shared/myfiles_dir` - upon repeated calls of `wget` from the same local working directory, the HTML of the directory listing will be saved as multiple copies e.g. `myfiles_dir.1`, `myfiles_dir.2` etc, in spite of any switches (although, the HTML directory listings will not be saved for any subdirectories inside, as requested; also, the very first time the command runs, there will not be a HTML directory listing saved for `myfiles_dir`).

However, with the trailing slash - as in `http://localhost/shared/myfiles_dir/` - no HTML directory listings will be saved for any directory, including the "root" `myfiles_dir`, after repeated calls to `wget` from the same local location.

Answer (score 1):

See also `-nH` a.k.a `--no-host-directories` and `--cut-dirs` options.  I also frequently use `--accept`/`-A` and `--reject`/`-R`.

Comment: Many thanks for these options, @jw013 - great to have a quick reference for them! Cheers!